# Jquery onchange select submit a form to PHP

Tags: jquery

I have no code to really show you here, but let's say I have a form with 3 HIDDEN fields that contain date, city and address.
I also have a select with 3 options (let's say Apple, Microsoft and Google).

What I want is that when a user changes the select to a different option, jquery should send the value of the selectbox + the 3 hidden fields to a PHP page, say proces.php. Proces.php handles the mysql_query etc, and it doesn't give anything back.

Can anyone show me how this is done? I don't expect anyone to write a whole script for me since I didn't provide any html code, but just the outline, or maybe a link to a tutorial or something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all your form should look something like this:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post" id="myForm">
    <select name="site" id="site">
        <option>Apple</option>
        <option>Google</option>
        <option>Microsoft</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="date" value="01/05/2012" />
    <input type="hidden" name="city" value="London" />
    <input type="hidden" name="address" value="[... address ...]" />
</form>
```

Then to submit via AJAX you would use the `serialize()` method to gather the form data:

```
$("#site").on("change", function() {
    var $form = $("#myForm");
    var method = $form.attr("method") ? $form.attr("method").toUpperCase() : "GET";
    $.ajax({
        url: $form.attr("action"),
        data: $form.serialize(),
        type: method,
        success: function() {
            // do stuff with the result, if you want to 
        }
    });
});
```

Alternatively if you don't want to use AJAX, just the standard form submission, you can trigger the form to submit, like this:

```
$("#site").on("change", function() {
    $("#myForm").submit();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, this seems to work, however it sends me to process.php, while I want process.php to run on its own in the background, and the user should not be directed to process.php, is that possible???

Comment: Yes - that's what my first example (using `$.ajax()`) does.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to send the form using jquery you can use Jquery Form plugin<
http://jquery.malsup.com/form/
so what basically u can do is to use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('form selector').ajaxForm(opts);
//u can define the opt urself itz easy look at the link
$("selects selector").change(function(){
$(form selector).ajaxSubmit(function(){//something you wanna do if form is submitted successfully})
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's see, so it's a form, and it's submitted when the dropdown select is changed?
You don't really need tu use AJAX for that.
You can use the jquery .change() method like this:

```
$('.mydropdown').change(function() {
  // Also do some checking to see if the values are not empty 
  // and then submit the form using:
  $('#myform').submit();
});
```

in the php file you can get them using the $_POST variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="#">
    <label for="brand">Brand</label>
    <select name="brand" id="brand">
        <option>Apple</option>
        <option>Microsoft</option>
        <option>Google</option>     
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="date" id="date" value="7/4/1776" />
    <input type="hidden" name="city" id="city" value="My City"  />
    <input type="hidden" name="address" id="address" value="123 Fake Street" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#brand').on('change',function() {
        $.post("process.php", $("#form1").serialize());
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```